# populate access table using dynamic column names

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

this is for an access 2016 db
I have say 50 tables that have a total of say 100 unique columns
so I can create a blank table with all 100 columns

so table 1 might have cols 1, 10, 99, table 2 might have cols 2, 15, 27, etc 
I would prefer to programmically iterate through the 50 tables in the db
and as I read the records for each table dynamically associate the col name and its data so I can populate a 100 column target record columns with whatever column data there is in current table and write out all the records. naturally there will be many blank fields in the 100 col record.  I know how to iterate through all tables and then get all the column names in each table, and get the table records data but can't figure out how to dynamically create the output records, actually not sure if it possible? 
If possible can somebody help with enough of a sample to get stated or links of course

Comment: You will get much better help if you post the code you have

Comment: don't really understand how I could use a cross tab query, but since I need to search  through a changing set of source tables was why I  thought I could only use vba.

Comment: here is how far I have got with vba

Comment: first part of code... too big for 1 postSub makeTable()
   Dim db As DAO.Database
   Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
   Dim fldSource As DAO.Field
   Dim fldTarget As DAO.Field
   Dim rstTable As DAO.Recordset
   Dim rstTargetTable As DAO.Recordset
   Dim rstSourceTable As DAO.Recordset
   Dim columnCount As Integer
   Dim colname, sheetname As String

   Set db = CurrentDb
   'this is the table with universe all columns to populate from source tables
   Set rstTargetTable = db.OpenRecordset("master")

Comment: 'second part of code
   Set db = CurrentDb
   'this is the table with universe all columns to populate from source tables
   Set rstTargetTable = db.OpenRecordset("master")
   For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
    ' iterate through all the potential source data tables
      If (tdf.Name Like "someID*") Then
         Set rstSourceTable = db.OpenRecordset(tdf.Name)

Comment: third part of code
         Do While Not rstSourceTable.EOF
            rstSourceTable.Next
            rstTargetTable.AddNew
            For Each fldSource In rstSourceTable.Fields
               For Each fldTarget In rstTargetTable.Fields
                  If fldSource.Name = fldTarget.Name Then
                     '??how to dynamically match target column with source column data
                     'need to set target col name to curr source rec current field name
                     rstTargetTable!matchingColName = rstSourceTable!currColName.Value
                  End I

Comment: fourth part of code
               Next 'next field in target table record
            Next 'field in current source table record
            rstTargetTable.Update
         End 'next record in source table
      rstSourceTable.Close
   Next 'next source table
End Sub

Comment: sorry about the long post, this is hard to follow I admit, I will post a link where all the code I have so can be seen in one place to make it more understandable

Comment: here is a link to the code I have so far  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BBzocvpgbkAq9mhDHAySLYjI3u-QDwB4/view

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say for sure without seeing your data but it sounds like a **Crosstab Query** will do the job.

> A **crosstab query** is a type of select query. When you run a crosstab
>   query, the results display in a datasheet that has a different
>   structure from other types of datasheets.
>
> The structure of a crosstab query can make it easier to read than a
>   simple select query that displays the same data, as shown in the
>   following illustration.
>
> [image: img]
>
> 1. This select query groups summary data vertically by employee and category.
> 2. A crosstab query can display the same data, but groups the data both horizontally and vertically so that the datasheet can be more
>      compact and easier to read.
>
> When you create a crosstab query, you specify which fields contain row
>   headings, which field contains column headings, and which field
>   contains values to summarize. You can use only one field each when you
>   specify column headings and values to summarize. You can use as many
>   as three fields when you specify row headings.
>
> You can also use an expression to produce row headings, column
>   headings, or values to summarize. See [SQL Aggregate Functions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sql-aggregate-functions-a810ee71-c1cd-43d7-9c55-8005f1893be5) for more
>   information.
>
> [image: img]
>
> 1. One, two, or three columns on this side contain **row headings**. The *names of the fields* that you use as row headings appear in the top row
>      of these columns.
> 2. The **row headings** appear here. The number of rows in the crosstab datasheet can grow quickly when you use more than one row heading
>      field, because each combination of row headings is displayed.
> 3. The columns on this side contain column headings and summary values. Note that the name of the column heading field does not appear
>      on the datasheet.
> 4. Summary values appear here.

More info at the [**Source**](https://support.office.com/article/make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-8465b89c-2ff2-4cc8-ba60-2cd8484667e8?ui=en-US&rs=en-CA&ad=CA) (and [elsewhere](https://www.google.com/search?q=crosstab%20queriy%20tutorial%20microsoft%20access))